# Simple File / Download Management Web Application

Tags: web, application

I'm looking for a simple web based download / file management application with the following features:

- categories
- custom fields (date and multi line text fields were missing from most ones I tested so far)
- screenshots for downloads
- multiple users (ideally ACLs for categories)
- download URL may be on another server

Platform does not matter that much, although a standard scripting language (PHP, Python, Ruby, Perl) and MySQL would mean less adaptions.

The ones I could find were either too simplistic, i.e. a better version of apache's directory listing, solutions one step away from Typo 3 or not touched within a few years.

Thanks & ciao,
Elmar Weber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, did some more searching and finally found one that fulfills all requirements:

http://www.phpcredo.com/Software/PHCDownload/

It has all features plus a ton more, but its admin interface is a little confusing.